# Suggestions for closing in a sunroom?

Tags: windows, screens

So I have this sunroom off the side of my garage that has a roof and what I think is a metal exterior.

[image]

1 wall is to the garage and the other 3 sides have large openings which once housed screens and about 18 horizontal glass panes that opened and closed on a crank. (Sorry, I do not have a good before pic, but this is the hardware left that cranks the windows open and closed)

[image]

Well, the windows were old, dirty, some cracked, some missing, and they were kindof an eyesore. The screens on the inside were in terrible shape. And the hardware that held the windows were also housing webs, nests, and hives for various creepy-crawly things. I took out the windows and screens and cleaned everything out and what you see in the first pic is the result. I love the way it looks and it's a great place for my daughter to play, but rain can get in now and there is no drainage. And we store things in the room in the winter (we are in Western NY).

I am looking for advice/recommendations for what to do with the openings that would be cheaper than putting in new windows/screens. I had an idea of taking out the window frames and getting vinyl sheets with magnets around the frame to lay against the metal. They can be rolled up when we want it open and closed for bad weather. But I don't know if that's even possible or practical.

If I don't come up with a solution, I need the frames in tact to put the screens and windows back up before next winter so that's why I haven't yet taken them down.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: I would make some wood frames that fit tight and put clear plastic on them. Then you can pop them out for the good weather. My first choice would be to order remodel Windows that fit the space that could be opened.